# How to extract certain part of line that's between quotes

Tags: grep

For example if I have `file.txt` with the following

```
object = {
   'name'             : 'namestring',
   'type'             : 'type',
   'real'             : 'yes',
   'version'          : '2.0',
}
```

and I want to extract just the `version` so the output is `2.0` how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that grep is probably the wrong tool for this.  Nevertheless, it is possible, using grep twice.

```
grep 'version' input.txt | grep -Eo '[0-9.]+'
```

The first grep isolates the line you're interested in, and the second one prints only the characters of the line that match the regex, in this case numbers and periods.  For your input data, this should work.

However, this solution is weak in a few areas.  It doesn't handle cases where multiple `version` lines exist, it's hugely dependent on the structure of the file (i.e. I suspect your file would be syntactically valid if all the lines were joined into a single long line).  It also uses a pipe, and in general, if there's a way to achieve something with a pipe, and a way without a pipe, you choose the latter.

One compromise might be to use awk, assuming you're always going to have things split by line:

```
awk '/version/ { gsub(/[^0-9.]/,"",$NF); print $NF; }' input.txt
```

This is pretty much identical in functionality to the dual `grep` solution above.

If you wanted to process multiple variables within that section of file, you might do something like the following with awk:

```
  BEGIN {
    FS=":";
  }

  /{/ {
    inside=1;
    next;
  }
  /}/ {
    inside=0;
    print a["version"];
    # do things with other variables too
    #for(i in a) { printf("i=%s / a=%s\n", i, a[i]); }    # for example
    delete a;
  }
  inside {
    sub(/^ *'/,"",$1); sub(/' *$/,"",$1);  # strip whitespace and quotes
    sub(/^ *'/,"",$2); sub(/',$/,"",$2);   # strip whitespace and quotes
    a[$1]=$2;
  }
```

A better solution would be to use a tool that actually understands the file format you're using.

Answer (score 0):

A simple and clean solution using `grep` and `cut`

```
grep version file.txt | cut -d \' -f4
```